# How to parse HTML in AutoHotKey?

Tags: javascript, html, autohotkey

I have problems with parsing HTML files. The thing is that all the examples I have seen so for are so complicated for a beginner and I don't understand them at all. I have read GetNestedTag manual but it seems that there is a better way: using HTML Dom.

I have many tags (not sure if this is the correct word) like:

`</span> 3272</p>`

`<h1 class="articleTitle">Title of text</h1>`

How do I get the text: "3272" in the first case and "Title of text" in the second case?

I have tried so far:

```
htmlCode = <h1 class="articleTitle">Title of text</h1>

html := ComObjCreate("HTMLFile")
html.write(htmlCode)

MsgBox % html.getElementsByClassName("articleTitle")[0].innerText\
```

And I have also tried:

```
IE := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible := true

IE.Navigate("http://archiwum.rp.pl/artykul/473989-Miller-rezygnuje-z-kierowania-SLD.html#.VwkZz_mLTcs" PostCode)

    while IE.readyState!=4 || IE.document.readyState != "complete" || IE.busy
        continue

   Sleep 1000

Title_element  := Name_Elements[A_Index-1].parentElement.getElementsByClassName("articleTitle")[0]
Title_text     := Title_element.innertext

msgbox, % title_text


ExitApp
```

In each case `MsgBox` fails to show the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to brush up on [Dom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) in order to properly navigate and parse websites using COM.

I'd suggest this thread here: [Basic Webpage Controls with JavaScript / COM - Tutorial](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/47052-basic-webpage-controls-with-javascript-com-tutorial/)

```
IE := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible := true

IE.Navigate("http://archiwum.rp.pl/artykul/473989-Miller-rezygnuje-z-kierowania-SLD.html#.VwkZz_mLTcs" PostCode)

    while IE.readyState!=4 || IE.document.readyState != "complete" || IE.busy
        continue

   Sleep 1000

Title_text := IE.document.getElementsByClassName("articleTitle")[0].innertext

MsgBox % Title_text
```